# WebView and touchesBegan event not rising !

Tags: iphone, events, uiwebview, uiviewcontroller, try-catch

I can't solve a problem ... And asking this question for second time. 
I want to describe my problem: I write class MiniBrowser inherit from UIViewController

```
@interface MiniBrowser : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>{
    IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;

@end
```

How you can see in this class I have a webViwe in witch I want to show some html code.

[image]

Now I want to **slide with finger to the right or left on the screen and catch that event** but I can't !!! I Read [this](http://mithin.in/2009/08/26/detecting-taps-and-events-on-uiwebview-the-right-way) article and test in this way but nothing happen !!! I am trying to catch touchesBegan event but it's never called !!! Who have any suggestion or any example of code please help me !!!

Thanks for answering this question !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK !!! I have done all !!! [This](http://mithin.in/2009/08/26/detecting-taps-and-events-on-uiwebview-the-right-way/) Article is perfect !!! If you have same problem and cant solve it write here if I can I will answer your questions !!! But in this Article you can find All only you must read carefully !!! And Read Comments they are very use-full for doing this !!! Have a luck !!!

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps

[Pass touch events to UIWebview](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/17121-fyi-how-pass-touch-events-uiwebview.html)

Comment: I can't understand how can I use this example ?